# MSIX WPF - Package.InstalledLocation Equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I've created an Windows Application Packaging Project for a WPF app.
The app runs fine and works with a ClickOnce installer.

I'm running into a problem with MSIX because I'm using an `appsetings.json` file, which I've set to `BuildAction=Content` and `Copy Always`.

In ClickOnce I can access that file using

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

However in my MSIX version I keep getting an error telling me that it can't find the file and that it was expecting to see it in "C:\WINDOWS\system32".

I've opened the MSIX Bundle with WinRar and the `appsettings.json` is in there.

In UWP apps I read that you can get the installed location with `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path`.

Is there an equivalent for WPF apps??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a packaged .NET Core desktop app, you should be able to get the path of the content file using the `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` property:

```
string absolutePath = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory + "appsetings.json";
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought if I marked as correct I couldn't up vote it. It's done now.